# List of Spark monitoring metrics names

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus, metrics, jmx-exporter

I'm trying to setup an infra for storing Spark metrics into Prometheus. I'm using the JMX Exporter with the following config

```
lowercaseOutputName: true
attrNameSnakeCase: true
rules:
- pattern: metrics<name=(\S+)\.driver\.(\S+)\.StreamingMetrics\.streaming\.(\S+)><>Value
  name: spark_streaming_$3
  labels:
    app_id: "$1"
    app_name: "$2"
- pattern: metrics<name=(\S+)\.driver\.(BlockManager|DAGScheduler)\.(\S+)><>Value
  name: spark_$2_$3
  labels:
    app_id: "$1"
```

I found those metrics patterns in this [blog post](https://argus-sec.com/monitoring-spark-prometheus/) which focus on Spark Streaming. Looking at the [Spark monitoring](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) configuration I was not able to find further information on those metrics names.

Where could I find an extensive list of those metric names, to create patterns like:

- (\S+).driver.(\S+).StreamingMetrics.streaming.(\S+)
- (\S+).driver.(BlockManager|DAGScheduler).(\S+)

Comment: The blog post shows how you can _browse_ the metrics exposed via JMX, by simply starting an idle `spark-shell` (for instance) then attaching an interactive console to the JVM running the driver. And you don't even need to expose an HTTP endpoint for that (could be done via a Linux pipe if the console runs under the same Linux account).

Comment: Note that newer Spark versions may introduce new metrics, with no more documentation than vague allusions in a JIRA; so it's a good thing to browse again on each release. Note also that some connectors (e.g. S3A) have their own set of JMX metrics, with just as little documentation.

Comment: On the other hand, you may want to inspect the JSON files produced for Spark HistoryServer. Normally they should contain the same exact "metrics" about jobs & tasks, but I'm not sure how the naming conventions in JSON match the naming conventions in JMX Beans.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I was thinking to inspect then one by one or expose everything to Prometheus and there do the discovery, but was wondering if there is any official documentation that could list them

Comment: When you get down to that level of detail, the only documentation is... the source code. That's the upside **and** the downside of Open Source software.

Comment: Spark 3 now has a native Prometheus exporter... that could save you a lot of pain. Along with JMX metrics from the executors forwarded to the driver. https://databricks.com/session_na20/native-support-of-prometheus-monitoring-in-apache-spark-3-0

Comment: cool thanks for the link, it seems that Spark 3 brought tons of new features.